# How to set cron email From field

Tags: cron, email

All my cron emails are sent to spam by gmail, which is not something I want. One of the thing that might put gmail off is that the raw email shows `From: root (Cron Daemon)`.

In the crontab I have both `MAILTO` and `MAILFROM` set up. I'd appreciate any pointers to solving this.

Comment: How do you send these emails? Is it just cron collecting the output of your jobs and sending it automatically? What if you did that yourself and sent it with the `mail` utility? I haven't seen a `MAILFROM` variable being mentioned in the cron manual.

Comment: Yes, just cron sending any output via email. Although for some thing a manual email might be the best solution actually, but getting the errors during cron processes is also very useful.